# when the static member of class be destroyed

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have to write a singleton class and I write the class as the Network said as follows. There's a inner class Collection aims at destroying the static member of my singleton class. It's said that the static member will be destroyed after the program running out. That's to say the destructor of class Collection will be called and "Call Destructor" can be seen in Output Window of VS. But after the program exit, I can't see the words. The static member collect hasn't be destroyed. How does this happen?

```
class Singleton  
{  
public:
    class Collection  
    {
    public:  
        ~Collection()  
        {  
            OutputDebugString(_T("Call Destructor\n"));  
        }  
    };  
    static Collection collect;  
};  

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  
{  
    Singleton s;  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller : That is an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @MartinBonner - Alright, hint taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static class members are destroyed at program termination, like all static objects are. They have to be defined however, which your example neglects to do. You only declare the member. A definition must still appear outside the class at namespace scope. So to fix it:

```
class Singleton  
{  
public:
    class Collection  
    {
    public:  
        ~Collection()  
        {  
            OutputDebugString(_T("Call Destructor\n"));  
        }  
    };  
    static Collection collect;  
};  

Singleton::Collection Singleton::collect;
```

Just define it.